# Adding ' active' to to html button doesn't apply the styles mentioned in the :active psuedo class

Tags: javascript, html, css

On clicking a button I want its color to be inverted.

Below is the html elements under concern:

```
    <div class='chatbot-container'>
      <div class='chatbot-wrapper' id='chatbot-wrapper' style="display:none;" >
        <iframe
          id="chatbot"
          class="chatbot"
          allow="microphone;"
          src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/xxx-xxx-xxx"></iframe>
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <button class='chat-btn' type="button" onclick="toggleChatbot()">Q</button>
    </div>
```

So here is my style sheet:

```
.chat-btn {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 32px;
    ....
    <code snipped for brevity>
    ...
}
.chat-btn:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: red;
}
.chat-btn:active {
    background: #fff;
    color: red;
}
```

Below is my script:

```
    <script>
      function toggleChatbot (chatBtn) {
        var x = document.getElementById("chatbot-wrapper");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
          chatBtn.className += ' active';
          console.log(chatBtn.active)
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
          chatBtn.className = chatBtn.className.replace(" active", "");
          console.log(chatBtn.active)
        }
      }
    </script>
```

So if you look at the below snapshot, 'active' is appended to the class as expected.
But the css psuedo class style is not being applied.
[image]

Comment: But `active` is a state not a class, it's just something that happens when a link is `active (the moment of click and that's it)` what would adding an `active` class do? also, as mentioned active is only for the moment of the click. if you're trying to color the link after the click you should use `:visited` instaed of `:active`. I guess this would work if you change in your css `.chat-btn:active` to `.chat-btn.active`

Comment: Please provide a code snippet to demonstrat the issue. Without html for the chat button (`chat_btn` element) and its wrapper (the `#chatbot_wrapper` element) it's difficult to assist.

Comment: @fedesc I tried adding :visited [```.chat-btn:visited {
    background: #fff;
    color: red;
}```], it didn't work. And besides I want it to toggle colors on every click, I want it to be white when it's active, and red when it's not. Wouldn't ```:active``` psuedo class mark the button as visited on the first click and leave it that way?

Comment: @traktor53 I added the html snippets :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you can't add a pseudo class to an element using JS as it's a pseudo class and not a real one. You could just create some other classes like `chat-btn-hover` which are similar to the pseudo classes!
This links may help you:

https://www.quora.com/Can-I-add-the-hover-pseudo-class-to-an-element-using-JavaScript

[Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: I don't who down voted your answer. But it worked, and was exactly what I was trying to do. I have did something similar to this, but forgot how exactly I achieved it.The below code, based on your idea worked.  ```if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
          chatBtn.className += ' chat-btn-active';
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
          chatBtn.className = chatBtn.className.replace(" chat-btn-active", "");
        }```  and ```.chat-btn-active {
    background: #fff;
    color: red;
}```